# How to read environment variables in azure devops pipeline using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I created a PowerShell job and used the below code to set the environment variable in the azure pipeline using Powershell.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("key", "value")
```

I can print the value using the `$env:key` in the same job itself.

But when I tried to display the value using `$env:key` in the next job nothing is printed. How to use the above environment variable through out the azure pipeline. Is there any other way to set and read custom environment variables.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks

Answer (score 2):

you pretty much have to either use [library variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#share-variables-across-pipelines) (or sets, dont remember the name) or you have to use a specific way to share variables across jobs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. We are not using the .Yml file. can we do this using PowerShell script?

Comment: @venkatesh you can switch samples to classic tab on the page as well as you can switch to powershell tab [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#use-output-variables-from-tasks)

Comment: what @ShamraiAleksander said, also you can just call ADO rest api from powershell and update variables in there

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks), `using outputs in a different job` is not supported in Classic UI Format.

As workarounds in this scenario, you can share variables via [Pipeline Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline)(share variables across jobs in same pipeline) or [Variable Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#share-variables-across-pipelines)(share variables across pipelines that use same Variable Group, it also works across jobs).

Since you only want to share variables across jobs in same pipeline, `pipeline variable` is enough for you.

1.You can set a `key` variable in pipeline variables:

[image]

2.Add one Powershell **Inline** task with content below in your first job:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/definitions/$($env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.0"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

# Update an existing variable to its new value
$pipeline.variables.key.value = "value"

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe key is updated to" $updatedef.variables.key.value
write-host "=========================================================="
```

3.Run the pipeline we can find the value of `key` variable is successfully updated:

[image]

So you can run the ps script in first job to update the value of `key` variable, then all next jobs can access the updated variable easily.

**Note:**

1. For the script itself, you only need to change lines `$pipeline.variables.key.value = "value"`(necessary) and `Write-host "The value of Varialbe key is updated to" $updatedef.variables.key.value`(optional).

If I want to set the variable named `MyTest` to value `MyValue`, the lines should be `$pipeline.variables.MyTest.value = "MyValue"` and `Write-host "The value of Varialbe MyTest is updated to" $updatedef.variables.MyTest.value`.

2. To make sure the ps task in one job can access `OAuth Token`, we should `Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token`. Click the agent job name and check the box:

[image]

3. To enable the pipeline has the permission to update pipeline variable (edit build pipeline), go pipeline security to set the `Edit build pipeline` **allow** for user `xxx(ProjectName) build service`.

[image]

Hope all above helps :)